# How to go back after I click the css link when I am in Inspect Element model in browser

Tags: css, debugging, browser, safari-web-inspector

This is my project when I am in Inspect Element model in Safari:
You can see the `editor.css` link on the right.

[image]

After I click the link, I come to `editor.css` detail:

[image]

But I don't know how to go back. Some one know how to go to the page ( 
go to the first snapshot )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just click on the first button at superior menu(dev tools menu, reading left to right. It has a reactangle icon). The button next to the inspector button(it is highlithed blue on the first screenshot)